# During + a time period (including a dash between two dates)

Tags: time

During 2000-2010

If I say it in English, should I say "during 2000 **and** 2010" or something else?

Comment: *During 2000 and 2010* means *During 2000 **and also during** 2010* (but not during the intervening years). If that's not the sense you intend, consider *during **the period** 2000 to 2010* or similar.

Answer (score 5):

Usually the en-dash is verbalized as "to":

> It happened during 2000–2010 = "It happened during two thousand to twenty ten."

With that said, this sounds like awkward construction to my ear. I would say that it's much more common to see:

> ...between 2000 and 2010.
>
> ...during the period 2000–2010. (pronounced "to" as shown above)
>
> ...during the period 2000 to 2010.

More generally, the en-dash (used for number ranges; slightly longer than a hyphen) can be spoken as either "to" or "through":

> The en dash is used to represent a span or range of numbers, dates, or time. There should be no space between the en dash and the adjacent material. Depending on the context, the en dash is read as “to” or “through.” ([Source](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html))

===

As a side note, you will frequently see:

> *...between 2000–2010.

Because the en-dash is typically pronounced as "to," this construction, though common, is considered less than ideal. It is preferably to write the conjunction out:

> ...between 2000 and 2010.

...or to use from/to:

> ...from 2000 to 2010.

For reference:

> A span of years (such as “2009–2012”) or any other time range includes an en dash. (And note that “from 2009–2012” and “between 2009–2012” are incorrect; either use both from and to, or between and and, or neither.) ([Source](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/use-a-dash-for-number-ranges/))

Comment: +1 I personally favor en dash over hyphen for number ranges, per CMoS, but note that the current MLA publication manual, without explicitly addressing the question, in fact uses hyphens. Your own usage in this post mixes the two, and where you most explicitly say en dash you are in fact using hyphen. (To enter an en dash when answering, either copy-paste one in or type &ndash; .)

Comment: Thanks, @BrianDonovan! I didn't know how to do en-dashes here... Great tip! Will fix the post next time I'm in front of the computer.